# Showing AlgebraicNumber[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), {-3, 2}] in human-readable way

Tags: output-formatting, number-representation

Is there a function to show algebraic numbers in Mathematica more conveniently? I am looking for something similar to MatrixForm for matrices.

For example, I would like to view `AlgebraicNumber[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), {-3, 2}]` as `-3 + 2*q`, where `q` is the generator of the number field my algebraic number comes from, i. e. `1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])` in this case.

I searched the documentation concerning algebraic numbers with no success. Something along the lines of
`Extract[AlgebraicNumber[...], {2}].{1, x}`
works, but it requires tweaking for different fields.

Comment: Have you heard about `ToRadicals` ?

Comment: I have not, thank you! It looks promising, but it also reduces the root the number field is based on.

Comment: Is this useful? `AlgebraicNumber[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), {-3, 2}] //. 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) -> q`

Comment: Yes, thanks, that does the job exactly! I take it there is probably no built in function for this? I guess not as this is very simple and neat solution already..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for [`AlgebraicNumberPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AlgebraicNumberPolynomial.html)?

```
AlgebraicNumberPolynomial[AlgebraicNumber[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), {-3, 2}], HoldForm[q]]
```

> ```
> -3 + 2 q
> ```

The question states: "... *show* algebraic numbers" and "I would like to *view* ..."  If you would like to display the `AlgebraicNumber` expression this way but retain its full syntax you can use a formatting function.  You typically have several choices including [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Format.html), [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MakeBoxes.html), and [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$PrePrint.html).  `MakeBoxes` is usually [preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119830/618728) for robustness and performance.  For example:

```
MakeBoxes[p : AlgebraicNumber[_, {__}], fmt_] :=
  ToBoxes[Interpretation[AlgebraicNumberPolynomial[p, HoldForm @ q], p], fmt]
```

Now:

```
AlgebraicNumber[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), {-3, 2}]
```

> ```
> -3 + 2 q
> ```

```
% // InputForm
```

> ```
> AlgebraicNumber[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2, {-3, 2}]
> ```

Comment: Seems like you've found the way to go (+1) but why do you need to play with `HoldForm` in `AlgebraicNumberPolynomial`, it seems to be superfluous.

Comment: Oh yes, this is awesome. Along the lines of A. C. Clarke, it looks like magic to me. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Artes In the case that `q` has a value assigned?  One could also use `\[FormalQ]`.

Comment: @BoZenKhaa Glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a reasonable application of `Replace`:

```
AlgebraicNumber[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), {-3, 2}] /. {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) -> q}
-3 + 2 q
```

The same replacement rule works for sums and products of `AlgebraicNumbers`.

As BoZenKhaa points out, if you don't know the exact form of the base, you can extract it and then do the replacement.

```
b = AlgebraicNumber[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), {-3, 2}];
b /. Extract[b, {1}] -> q
-3 + 2 q
```

Comment: I am using algebraic number b as the base of the number field, and this slight change works for me:

AlgebraicNumber[..] //. Extract[b, {1}] -> x

Comment: @BoZenKhaa I guess you shouldn't play with `Replace` since it doesn't work when `AlgebraicNumber` yields the `Root` objects.

Comment: That is a good point, however it works with the `Extract`. I will not be using the results for any computations, just presentation, so I feel safe :-)