# How to define an expression which is differently evaluated in calculations and printed

Tags: programming, evaluation, syntax

Let's say, we have a list:

```
values = {1.2, 0.04, 0.9};
```

Is it possible to replace `0.04` by some expression, which displays as `nearly zero` when printed, but evaluates still to `0.04` when inserted into another Mathematica expression? I tried

```
values = {1.2, Interpretation["nearly zero",0.04], 0.9};
```

but this does not work. Although

```
Print[values];
```

indeed gives as output

```
{1.2,nearly zero,0.9}
```

but `numericalValues = 1+values` evaluates to

```
{2.2,1+"nearly zero",1.9}
```

not the expected

```
{2.2,1.04,1.9}
```

Comment: I've done this a couple of times, and maybe these examples help explain the general procedure: [How to make traditional output for derivatives](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23664/245), [Can I enter the traditional form for Binomial as input in an expression?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45489/245). If those answers are what you want, I could repeat a summary of the necessary steps and write it as an answer. That could also address what @Kuba is looking for in his comment.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define how you expect this special object to interact with functions, and *which* functions should handle it.  Based on your example I think you want the label to be stripped from the object when an operation is performed?

- You can generally use [`UpSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSet.html) or [`TagSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html) (or more frequently their Delayed counterparts) to provide handling rules as needed.
- Display is most robustly handled by defining a [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html) rule for your object but [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) can work too.

Perhaps you only want a limited number of functions to operate on your object.  Then:

```
MakeBoxes[note[val_, name_], form_] := ToBoxes[name, form]

note /: note[val_, name_] + x_. := val + x
note /: note[val_, name_] * x_. := val * x
```

Now:

```
values = {1.2, note[0.04, "nearly zero"], 0.9}
```

> ```
> {1.2, "nearly zero", 0.9}
> ```

```
1 + values
```

> ```
> {2.2, 1.04, 1.9}
> ```

Or if you want *most* functions to operate in this manner you can choose which heads "hold" your object unevaluated:

```
ClearAll[note]

MakeBoxes[note[val_, name_], form_] := ToBoxes[name, form]

$noteHolders = {List, foo};

note /: head_[a___, note[val_, name_], b___] := 
  head[a, val, b] /; FreeQ[$noteHolders, head]
```

The global variable `$noteHolders` is a list of Symbols that should *not* evaluate `note` when the appear as the head of an expression.  It may be updated at will if you define or find new functions that need to hold `note` unevaluated.

Test:

```
values = {1.2, note[0.04, "nearly zero"], 0.9}
1 + values
```

> ```
> {1.2, "nearly zero", 0.9}
>
> {2.2, 1.04, 1.9}
> ```

```
foo[1.2, note[0.04, "nearly zero"], 0.9]
bar[1.2, note[0.04, "nearly zero"], 0.9]
```

> ```
> foo[1.2, "nearly zero", 0.9]
>
> bar[1.2, 0.04, 0.9]
> ```

If you want to be able copy the output `"nearly zero"` and use it as input you will need to create an `InterpretationBox` in the `MakeBoxes` rule; see for example:

- [How can one define a custom data object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/how-can-one-define-a-custom-data-object/2616#2616)
- [How can I make Which format its output?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28868/how-can-i-make-which-format-its-output/28884#28884)
- [Displaying index as subscript on output: e.g. C[i] -> C_i with Notation[...] or Interpretation[..]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30884/displaying-index-as-subscript-on-output-e-g-ci-c-i-with-notation-or/30886#30886)
- [Showing AlgebraicNumber[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), {-3, 2}] in human-readable way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38672/showing-algebraicnumber1-2-1-sqrt5-3-2-in-human-readable-way/38678#38678)
- [Why doesn't a Composition[] hold its arguments and what can be done about it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54762/why-doesnt-a-composition-hold-its-arguments-and-what-can-be-done-about-it/54769#54769)
- [Display All Output Numbers in HEX](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61465/121)

Also however see this warning about the loss of "editability" that will result:

- [Why does TraditionalForm[Inactivate[x y]] show x * y ? instead of x y?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56246/why-does-traditionalforminactivatex-y-show-x-y-instead-of-x-y/56715#56715)

Comment: Such questions appear from time to time. I think it is confusing, it was for me at least, what is the purpose of `Format, Interpretation, TagBox, HoldForm, UpValues` etc., and what are relations between them. Those doubts are expressed and answered in many places here but what is missing is nice compact quide + short examples for real life needs. (Explanation that secific functions creates specific box is not what people need) If you or anyone else will do this I will certainly give a bounty for this. Meanwhile, +1 :)

Comment: +1. Nice collection; I tried to use `Format[ nearZero[ val_] ]` together with `Interpretation` but that does not work out as nicely. It really seems to be about "to hold or not to hold".